# Is there a Google Sheet function that can use 2 values and return its the value where they intersect?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm currently doing preppin'data challenge and I encountered this Table:

```
Online or In-Person,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4
Online,72500,70000,60000,60000
In-Person,75000,70000,70000,60000
```

Question: Is there any function where I can use "Online" and "Q1" as parameters to get the value 72500 or any custom equation you might suggest?

| Online or In-Person | Q1 |
| --- | --- |
| Online | 72500 |
| In-Person | 75000 |

I think the easiest way for me to generate the corresponding "Q1" and "Online" value using vlookup would be restructuring the table and make a helper column where I'd Concatenate "Online" and Q1 but I'm looking for a solution where I don't have to create and entire new table.

Comment: INDEX and 2 MATCH functions - one for the row and one for the column.

Comment: I gave you a [few options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76526261/11262439)  You can come up with some other creative ways as well

Answer (score 0):

You have many approaches available to you.

### VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP with MATCH

You can use either of the [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) or [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375?hl=en) functions, and the [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) function to provide their `index` argument.

**Syntax**

- `VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])`
- `HLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])`
- `MATCH(search_key, range, [search_type])`

```
=VLOOKUP("Online", A1:E3, MATCH("Q1", A1:E1, 0), 0)

=HLOOKUP("Q1", A1:E3, MATCH("Online", A1:A3, 0), 0)
```

[image]

[image]

### INDEX with MATCH

<sup>* *This was also recommended by @Rory in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76525214/is-there-a-google-sheet-function-that-can-use-2-values-and-return-its-the-value#comment134927594_76525214)*</sup>

Using the [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) function with two [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)  functions; one for each of its `row` and `column` arguments

**Syntax**

- `INDEX(reference, [row], [column])`
- `MATCH(search_key, range, [search_type])`

```
=INDEX(A1:E3, MATCH("Q1",A1:E1,0), MATCH("Online",A1:A3,0))
```

[image]

### Nested FILTER

The first [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) function returns the column, and second returns the row.

- `FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, …])`

```
=FILTER(FILTER(B2:E3, B1:E1="Q1"), A2:A3="Online")
```

[image]